# How can reversible reactions be exothermic or endothermic?

Tags: energy

So this may be a dumb question, but because the forward reaction of a reversible reaction releases the sane amount of energy as the backwards reaction absorbs (because the bonds that are formed from the forwards reaction are broken by the backwards reaction and vice versa) and at equilibrium both reactions occur at the same rate, surely in a reversible reaction the rate of energy release to the environment is equal to the energy absorbed by the environment. So how can there be any net loss/gain of energy to the environment like what is needed for an exothermic/endothermic reaction? I don't understand.

Comment: A reversible reaction starts with a chemical composition which is out of equilibrium. So the system releases some energy to the environment or absorbs energy from the environment.The chemical composition of the system slowly changes, and evolves towards the final state of equilibrium. At equilibrium, no heat is exchanged with the environment, and both reactions occur with the same rate.

Comment: Okay so its what happens before equilibrium is reached that releases/absorbs the energy. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: The gist? Reactions rarely start at equilibrium.

Comment: See $\ce{NO2}$ - $\ce{N2O4}$ demo, https://chemdemos.uoregon.edu/demos/NO2N2O4-Equilibrium-Demonstration# , to see how temperature affects equilibrium.